# Play music app doesn't find transferred mp3 file in library

Tags: motorola-moto-e, shareit

I transferred an mp3 file from my PC using SHAREit app to my Android phone. It stored the received file it's own directory (SD1\Android\data\com.google...\files\SHAREit\audio\ on SD card. However I copied that file to another but already existing directory on SD card. Later I removed the file from the SHAREit path.

Now I can play this mp3 by directly going to the current directory and tapping on the file name. But this mp3 can not be seen or played by "Play Music" app.

Can you help me?

Thanking you
Shashidhar

Comment: Is there a *.no media* file in that directory-if yes, try deleting that

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply. However immediately after posting question, I just tried rebooting the android phone. After re-booting, the mp3 file in question was seen and played by the "Play Music" app. So this worked for me. But I didn't understand what .no media file is.

Thank you anyway. 
May God bless you
Shashidhar